# Docker compose: extend common block, not override it

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
x-common-elements:
  &common-elements
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
    - PUID=1000
    - PGID=1000
    - VERSION=docker
  volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro


services:
  my_service:
    <<: *common-elements
    image: my_image
    environment:
      - ENV=dev
    volumes:
      - $HOME/config:/config
```

How do I configure this so that the environment and volume configured under my_service don't override the volumes under common-elements, but extend them instead? I want both the localtime and config volumes to be present there. Is this possible with docker compose?

Note that I have a lot of services, so just repeating volumes and variables every time is not a great solution.